# Disable menubutton in the android emulator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

When developing applications for ICS - the actionbar looks different depending on if there is a physical menubutton present on the device or not.

For example if not, a virtual button is displayed in the actionbar.

Is it possible to emulate a device without a menubutton by disabling it somehow in the emulator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an option "hardware back/home keys". Specify the option and set it to "no" when creating the virtual device.

Comment: absolutely correct, thats the way to create emulator for ICS, tried to create emulator for google nexus device.. thx, i wonder why this answer is not accepted yet

Comment: Where can I find the hardware back/home keys and No? It seems that I couldn't find it. Help.

Comment: If you create a vitual device using the eclipse integration there will be a combo box in the dialog where you specify the porperties of the device. With the combo box you can select a property like the one mentioned in the answer. Then a window will pop up aksing you for the property's value.

Answer (score 11):

Open the `AVD Manager, Click`Show on Disk`option, Edit the`config.ini`file from the opened directory, find`hw.mainKeys`config and set it to`yes`

```
hw.mainKeys = yes
```

Save the file and restart the AVD.

Refer screenshots below for more details
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

With updated SDK tool (R22 as of this answer), the AVD manager editor no longer expose these options on the UI.  You have to edit the **config.ini** of your AVD manually and change the following key from

`hw.mainKeys=yes`

to

`hw.mainKeys=no`

Comment: Remember, that the config.ini is placed in your user directory.
In Windows: C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\avd\YOUR_AVD_NAME.avd\config.ini

Comment: and the path in Mac is /Users/USERNAME/.android/avd/YOUR_AVD_NAME.avd/config.ini

Comment: The path in linux is `~/.android/avd/YOUR_AVD_NAME.avd/config.ini`. I actually had to set it to `hw.mainKeys=yes` to remove the software buttons at the bottom. I wanted to remove them from screenshots.

Comment: The path in Android Studio 3 on macOS is now: `~/.android/avd/`

Answer (score 4):

As @Yenchi said, tick on 'hw.mainKeys'.
The virtual device will look like second picture.

[image]
[image]